# Passing list<object> to thymeleaf with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have part of the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="1", required = false, defaultValue = "1") int id, Model model){

    List<Question> survey = surveyDAO.getSurveyById(id);
    model.addAttribute("survey", survey);
    return "showSurvey";
}
```

where I try to addAttribute List<Question> to be passed on to thymeleaf page. But on the thymeleaf side I only get the "cannot resolve" error.

Part of the .html in showSurvey.html

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr th:each="survey: ${survey}">
            <td th:text="${survey">1</td>
            <!-- <td><a href="#" th:text="${message.name}">Title ...</a></td>-->
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Packaging with mvn package and then running the jar starts up the application, and it works, but crashes when trying to resolve "survey" on showSurvey.html so `SurveyDAO.GetSurveyById(id);` actually comes back properly.

So how should I go about passing the list and then showing proper values out of it? It has two int and String for all that matters.

Comment: `<td th:text="${survey">1</td>` doesnt look right. It has to be something like this `<td th:text="${survey.id}">1</td>`.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right! tho i just took it out to try with just the object but the result was same, thymeleaf cant resolve the incoming list at all.

Comment: Please also post the stacktrace.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Turns out it was just a typo tho...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a right "}" - I have just tested this, and it works fine:

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="survey : ${survey}">
        <td th:text="${survey}">1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comments your code doesn't look right.

Fix your code like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr th:each="survey: ${survey}">
            <td th:text="${survey.id}">1</td> // id is a property of the Question class
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```